# Compute the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-3}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus

How can I compute the next limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-3}{n^2}$$

Do you have any advise or any role. I was considering

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-3}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left({i-3}\right)\frac{1}{n^2}$

I know that this serie is convergent but I do not know how to compute can you help me.

Comment: Hint: Use the well-known formula $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i-3) = \sum_{i=1}^3 (i-3) + \sum_{i=4}^n (i-3) =\\=-2 + (-1) + 0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-3} k = -3 + \frac{(n-3)(n-2)}{2}$$

Also,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

1.
$$\frac{A}{D} + \frac{B}{D} + \frac{C}{D} =\frac{1}{D}(A+B+C)$$
2. 
$$ (A-D) + (B-D) + (C-D) = A+B+C - 3D$$
3. 
$$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$